# 2 questions regarding !LOOP in iMacros

Tags: string, loops, imacros

So my first question is very simple, let's say I want to say "catdog" repeatedly but add the amount of loops at the end of it (i.e. catdog57), how would I accomplish that? I know I can use {{!LOOP}} to use the variable in the each loop, but how do I incorporate it into a string? Using + signs doesn't seem to work and simply leaving it there doesn't either. I would be incorporating it into the following line of code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:username-input CONTENT=catdog
```

Second question is, how can I do the same but add a number to the loop count, such as 2 for instance? So if the current loop is 50, it would add 52 at the end instead of 50.

Answer (score 0):

First answer:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:username-input CONTENT=catdog{{!LOOP}}
```

Second answer:

```
SET number EVAL({{!LOOP}}+2)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:login-form ATTR=ID:username-input CONTENT=catdog{{number}}
```

Comment: Thanks Shugar. You're like the only person on here who answers iMacros questions lol.

Comment: Definitely not the only one, but the one of those persons.